# JFrame Number Input

Tags: java, swing, input, jframe

I'm building a Swing application with `JFrame` and `FlowLayout`. There are two `ComboBox`es containing `Strings` with item names. I want to be able to specify the quantity of said items.

First, I considered using `JTextField`s, but they can take any `String` as input. There are ways to force numeric input, but I remembered another type of input field I'd seen before.

I can't seem to find the name of the numeric input field (see http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_number for HTML5 version). This field only takes numbers and has the two arrow buttons to make slight adjustments to the value therein.

Is this in Swing, or will I need to get a library to do this? If it is, what is the name of the field? If not, what libraries can accomplish this?

Comment: How to use Spinners - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Oracle's [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html):

> Spinners are similar to combo boxes and lists in that they let the user choose from a range of values. Like editable combo boxes, spinners allow the user to type in a value. Unlike combo boxes, spinners do not have a drop-down list that can cover up other components. Because spinners do not display possible values — only the current value is visible — they are often used instead of combo boxes or lists when the set of possible values is extremely large. However, spinners should only be used when the possible values and their sequence are obvious.

[image: Spinner Demo]

Comment: 1+. to the original poster, this is the solution you should use.

Comment: This was precisely what I was looking for. I just had no idea what they were called.

Answer (score 0):

> There are ways to force numeric input, but I remembered another type
>   of input field I'd seen before.

There is no such Text Component available to Swing which can work with numeric input directly, as much as i know. But nothing should stop you to extend the existing `JTextFeild` and declare your own required function. For example, to work with integer value:

```
class MyTextField extends JTextField
{
    public void setIntValue(int x)
    {
        setText(""+x);
    }
    public int getIntValue()
    {
        return Integer.parseInt(getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JNumberField. This Field returns an integer. But you can even type numbers in JTextField and parse it into int.

Comment: Where is the JNumberField described in the API? I've not heard of this entity. If this is a not part of core Java, then you'll want to post a link to its source.

Comment: Do you mean JFormattedTextField perhaps?

Comment: `JNumberField` doesn't exist. Spinner seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: http://www.compchemcons.com/webenabling/API_doc/JosAertsBeans/JNumberField.html We are talking about Java Swing are we?!

Comment: @Pixell: what library is that from -- it's certainly not part of core Java or the standard Swing library?